# File System Root - Low Disk Space - PARTIAL folder

Tags: apt, disk, storage

I use Ubuntu at work and recently I have been receiving a message during boot up that states the file system is low on disk space and at one point the desktop would not fully load.

After using Disk Usage Analyzer, I narrowed the bulky folder down to /var/lib/apt/lists/partial.  The **partial** folder has like 60 to 80 gigabytes of data in it which is the bulk of the problem. Inside this folder is tons of archive.ubuntu.com files and the largest is **archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dist_vivid-updates_main_binary-i386_Packages** and other smaller similar files.  Are these related to the update process? Important? Need a little light shine on it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

They are not important to the update system, because that are the partially downloaded package lists. And you can clean the cache of apt with sudo apt-get  clean.

Comment: I ran that a few times but the files remain.

Comment: You can delete the files in the partial folder

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
$ sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/*
```

Comment: I think it is just 1 * at the end

Answer (score -1):

Open a terminal and write the following

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install bleachbit
sudo bleachbit
```

And delete all the unuseful files on Ubuntu

Comment: This doesn't specify what is useful or not - randomly deleting files can be dangerous and can nuke the system.